# Manage Phone Audio Player through Car Stereo over Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, music-player, bluetooth-audio

I spent yesterday evening looking through Q&A and I see this question asked in different ways, but not answered. I will try to make the question very clear.

I have a bluetooth-enabled car stero (Kenwood). I have a bluetooth-enabled Android phone (Samsung). I can pair the two without trouble. They automatically pair every time I get in the car. On the phone, I can enable bluetooth call control and  bluetooth audio control.

What I want to do is get in my car, turn on the stereo, and press the play button to start playing music from my phone. I cannot do that. What I have to do is get in my car, turn on the stereo, get my phone, open a music player app on the phone, press play on the music player app, and put my phone away again.

I downloaded a variety of Kenwood apps, but they are all USB apps, not bluetooth apps. Is there some way to make a phone start playing music by pressing play on the stereo?

In response to the comment below...
At lunch today, I went out to a coworker's car. She had her phone in her purse. She started her car and turned on the radio. She pressed "source" to change it from FM to BT. The radio showed playlists on her phone. She scrolled through the list and selected one. It started playing. She never took her phone out of her purse. She did everything from the radio. So, how can I expect the phone to respond to pressing a button on the radio? Simple. It does that for other people. I want mine to do it for me. I want to know how such a dismissive comment gets a +1.

Comment: Seconding that. All I can think of is auto-pairing to cause your car stereo swtiching to the "new input", and then controling it like a BT headset with buttons would do. But I've got no experience in that field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highly depends on the bluetooth profile and capabilities of your stereo. Some only implement call button profiles, some implement audio only and some support audio and buttons. Some have advance support for Playlist and file system. A FM Bluetooth adapter I had could play and stop my music but couldn't see play lists or anything.

If you press the play button twice does it work? Or long press? If you play your music, do the buttons play at that point? But in any case, there is no way to really change it, without replacing the stereo.